# Fuzzy Match values to list of list python

Tags: python, fuzzy

Struggling with how to do this in a pythonic way. I have a list of list which we can call names

```
[('Jimmy', 'Smith'), ('James', 'Wilson'), ('Hugh' "Laurie')]
```

And then I have a two variables

```
First_name = 'Jimm'

Last_name = 'Smitn'
```

I want to iterate through this list of list, of first and last names to fuzzy match these values and return the list that is the closest to the specified First_name and Last_name

Comment: Take a look on [`difflib.SequenceMatcher`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/difflib.html#sequencematcher-objects). `max(lst, key=lambda x: SequenceMatcher(None, " ".join(x), " ".join((First_name, Last_name))).ratio())`

Comment: That worked beautifully! Thank you @OlvinRoght! if you put that in an answer, I will happily upvote it

Comment: Fuzzy matching is not a clearly defined concept. If you do not want to come up with your own, *precise* rules that tell you whether something is a match, then you will have to use a third-party library that has its own assumptions built in. In the first case, the question is not properly focused, and otherwise it asks for third-party library recommendations. Either way, the question is not [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement fuzzy matching obtaining best match ratio *(using [`max()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max))*  returned by [`difflib.SequenceMatcher()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/difflib.html#difflib.SequenceMatcher).

To implement this we should pass [`lambda`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#lambda) as `key` argument which will return match ratio. In my example I'd use [`SequenceMatcher.ratio()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/difflib.html#difflib.SequenceMatcher.ratio), but if performance is important you should also try with [`SequenceMatcher.quick_ratio()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/difflib.html#difflib.SequenceMatcher.quick_ratio) and [`SequenceMatcher.real_quick_ratio()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/difflib.html#difflib.SequenceMatcher.real_quick_ratio).

```py
from difflib import SequenceMatcher

lst = [('Jimmy', 'Smith'), ('James', 'Wilson'), ('Hugh', 'Laurie')]
first_name = 'Jimm'
last_name = 'Smitn'

matcher = SequenceMatcher(a=first_name + ' ' + last_name)
match_first_name, match_last_name = max(lst,
    key=lambda x: matcher.set_seq2(' '.join(x)) or matcher.ratio())

print(first_name, last_name, '-', match_first_name, match_last_name)
```

Comment: I'm changing this feature to now filter out matches less than n (e.g. 90). This is what I have, but it doesn't seem to return what I want

Comment: matches = filter(lambda x: SequenceMatcher(None, " ".join(x), " ".join((First_Name, Last_Name))).ratio() > .90, lst)

Comment: @ChessGuy, you can use either simple list comprehension *(`[i for i in lst if matcher.set_seq2(' '.join(i)) or matcher.ratio() > 0.9]`)* or apply `filter()` *(`list(filter(lambda l: matcher.set_seq2(' '.join(l)) or matcher.ratio() > 0.9, lst))`)*.

Answer (score 1):

Another possible path would be to use set intersections.

```
names = [('Jimmy', 'Smith'), ('James', 'Wilson'), ('Hugh', 'Laurie')]
first_name = "Jimm"
last_name = "Smitn"

setf = set(first_name)
# {'m', 'i', 'J'}
setl = set(last_name)
# {'t', 'n', 'm', 'i', 'S'}

ranked = [(len(setf & set(f)) + len(setl & set(l)), f, l) for f, l in names]
# [(7, 'Jimmy', 'Smith'), (4, 'James', 'Wilson'), (1, 'Hugh', 'Laurie')]

best_match = max(ranked, key=lambda x: x[0])[1:]
# ('Jimmy', 'Smith')
```

Comment: Nice implementation. You can omit `key` argument, python use lexicographical order so first item will be compared by default. Also you can use `setf.intersection(f)` and `setl.intersection(l)` which should be slightly faster.